# shoulda-matchers validate_uniqueness_of returns scoped when not scoped

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I recently upgraded to rails 5, and at the same time upgraded the gem shoulda-matchers.

I have a `User` model with an `email` attribute
the email should be unique, and this uniqueness is case insensitive

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   validates :email, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end
```

I'm testing this using rspec

```
RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
  subject { build(:user) }
  [...]
     it { is_expected.to validate_uniqueness_of(:email).ignoring_case_sensitivity }
end
```

But it throws this error

```
Expected User to validate that :email is unique, but this could not be proved.
Expected the validation not to be scoped to anything, but it was scoped to :provider instead.
```

I'm using devise in case this could help.

kinda lost here, specially since it used to be working fine

thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Devise adds a uniqueness validation on email if you are using the [validatable module](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb). Validations can be thought of as cumulative so `validates :email, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }` does not replace the existing validation - it just adds a another validation.

What you need to do is remove the validateable module:

```
devise :invitable, :omniauthable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :confirmable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable
```

And implement the validations yourself. But I would really consider if it a good idea in the first place. Do you really want duplicates of `foo@example.com` and `Foo@example.com`?

Comment: Yes you can remove the validation and `.ignoring_case_sensitivity` from the spec.

Comment: I did remove ```validates :email, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }``` and I still get the same error

Comment: I'm using `devise_token_auth` instead of devise and even I'm also facing the same issue, removing ` validates :email, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }` still raises the error `Expected the validation not to be scoped to anything, but it was scoped to :provider instead.`  Is it because of `provider` column provided by devise_token_auth? @MikeW did you find the solution?